# Push operation not working while pushing array to a hash

Tags: perl

I have two arrays `@arr1` and `@arr2` and I have a hash `%hash` in my Perl code.

I have certain elements in `@arr1` and similarly certain elements in `@arr2`. I want to push elements of `@arr1` as key for hash `%hash` and elements of the array `@arr2` as values for those keys for hash `%hash`.

I am using the below code in my Perl script to do so:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my %hash = ();
my @abc = ('1234', '2345', '3456', '4567');
my @xyz = ('1234.txt', '2345.txt', '3456.txt', '4567.txt');

push(@{$hash{@abc}}, @xyz);
print Dumper(%hash);
```

After executing, I am getting the below output:

```
./test.pl

$VAR1 = '4';
$VAR2 = [
          '1234.txt',
          '2345.txt',
          '3456.txt',
          '4567.txt'
        ];
```

It is not printing the key values but their total number. I need the output to be that every key with its value gets printed after I execute the script.

Can someone please help. Thanks.

Comment: Also: `print Dumper(\%hash);`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're looking for a [slice](https://perldoc.perl.org/perldata#Slices) to assign multiple elements of a hash at once:

```perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my %hash = ();
my @abc = ('1234', '2345', '3456', '4567');
my @xyz = ('1234.txt', '2345.txt', '3456.txt', '4567.txt');

@hash{@abc} = @xyz;
print Dumper(\%hash);
```

produces (Though order of keys might vary):

```
$VAR1 = {
          '4567' => '4567.txt',
          '2345' => '2345.txt',
          '3456' => '3456.txt',
          '1234' => '1234.txt'
        };
```

---

##### Explanation

What `push(@{$hash{@abc}}, @xyz);` does is push elements into an array reference stored in a single hash entry - `@abc` is used in scalar context here, which evaluates to the length of the array, hence the 4. Using a slice instead assigns a list of values to a corresponding list of keys.

Then `print Dumper(%hash);` first turns `%hash` into a list of alternating keys and values, hence them being two different `Data::Dumper` entries. Passing a reference to the hash instead makes it print out the actual data structure as one thing.

Comment: Also see [`mesh`](https://metacpan.org/pod/List::Util#mesh) from `List::Util` for an alternative that was useful before slices.